# How do I convert sympy expression into a graph?

Tags: python, sympy

How do I convert the following equation, as a function of f_**q** (which is a function of 2D-vector **q**) into a graphical representation?

[image]

It may be easier to consider something like y = sin(x) for the explanation however

Comment: What do you mean by graph? Like you want to plot the expression, or you want a graph (nodes and edges) of the expression tree, or something else?

Comment: Just a plot of the expression, omega_q vs q (where f_q is a known function of q)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sympy has it's own [plotting module](https://docs.sympy.org/1.5.1/modules/plotting.html). This module is mostly for convenience, to rapidly view a function without the need to leave sympy. There are very limited options for formatting.

Plotting  `y=sin(x)` is just:

```py
from sympy import plot, sin
from sympy.abc import x
plot(sin(x))
```

But that is only for 1D functions. To plot 2D functions, [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) is the go-to library. The simplest would be a 2D plot using color as a 3 dimension. Nicer and more informative plots can be got from 3D plots. Matplotlib standardly allows interacting with them to be viewed from different directions.

Here is an example:

```py
from sympy import sin, lambdify
from sympy.abc import x, y, a, b

f = sin(a*x*y+b) / (x*x+y*y+1)
# convert to a numpy function, make sure all variables apart from x and y have a fixed value
f_np = lambdify((x,y), f.subs({a: 1.5, b: 1}), 'numpy')


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2,2,100), np.linspace(-2,2,100))
z = f_np(x, y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, edgecolor='none', cmap='terrain')

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

See [this interesting site](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.12-three-dimensional-plotting.html%20for%20more%20ideas%20around%203D%20plotting) for more ideas about 3d plotting.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I suppose we'll find out if it's so simple for functions of functions, which it should be I'd hope

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install matplotlib but then you should be able to do

```
>>> plot(x**2 + 1)
```

For your example you would have to give values for all parameters in order to see a plot wrt q, e.g.

```
>>> plot(omega_q.subs([(omega0, 1), (Omega,2)]))
```

See the documentation on plotting in the doc/src/modules/plotting.rst