# Convert sympy formula to values: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'float'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

I'm trying to draw a "spherical coordinate system" 3D formula using matplotlib and sympy.

the formula was calculated as sympy formula,
but I can't convert formula to values.

I need to convert `result` to `numpy.ndarray` for matplotlib.

I want to create numpy array, but I get array of sympy function!
the commented lines are the codes I was test :|

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import math

fact = math.factorial #sp.factorial
exp = sp.exp
cos = np.cos #sp.cos
sin = np.sin #sp.sin
pi = sp.pi #np.pi

count = 20
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, count)
phi = np.linspace(0, np.pi, count)

n = 3 #int(input("n:"))
l = 2 #int(input("l:"))
m = 2 #int(input("m:"))

def sqrt_n(x, n):
    return x**(1/float(n))

def diff(f, n):
    fn = f
    for i in range(n):
        fn = sp.diff(fn)
    return fn

# some other calculation functions ...

def PSI(n,l,m, r, theta, phi):
    a1 = (2/n)**3
    a2 = fact(n-l-1)
    a3 = 2*n* fact(n+l)**3
    a = a1 * a2 / a3
    b = exp(-r/n)
    c = sp.diff(2*r/n)
    d = L2(2*l+1,n-l-1, 2*r/n)
    #e = Y(m,l, theta,phi)
    return sp.sqrt(a) * b * c * d #* e

x = sp.Symbol('x')
result = PSI(n,l,m, x,theta,phi)

# THE PROBLEM: HOW TO CONVERT? <<<<<<<<<<

#R = result.rhs
R = sp.lambdify(x, result, 'numpy')
#eqR = sp.Eq(result, 0)
#R = sp.solve(eqR, x)

THETA, PHI = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)
# HERE THE ERROR OCCURS: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'float' <<<<<<<<<<
XX = R * np.sin(PHI) * np.cos(THETA)
YY = R * np.sin(PHI) * np.sin(THETA)
ZZ = R * np.cos(PHI)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
plot = ax.plot_surface(XX, YY, ZZ)
plot = ax.plot_wireframe(XX, YY, ZZ, color='w', linewidth=0.05)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `R`, produced by `lambdify` if a **function**, not a value or number.  I'd suggest doing a `help(R)` to see what it produced.  You might also want to `print(result)`, both for your benefit an ours.  You are mixing `sympy` and `numpy` to such an extent that it's hard to picture what's going on, and what, if anything, is working as intended.

Comment: ```type(result)``` is ```sympy.core.mul.Mul``` but I want to convert it to ```numpy.ndarray```

Comment: You have to apply `R` on some numerical values to have a numpy array. Note that you can't mix numpy and sympy in this way.  You first need some code that is fully symbolic and that ends with lambdifying a function (of one or more parameters).  From then on, you'd only use numerical functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sympy doesn't mix well with numeric libraries. It is best to separate-out all sympy functionality to a part of the code that doesn't use numpy, math or similar libraries.  At the end, you call `func_np = sp.lamdify((param1, param2, param3),func)` and from then on you stay away from sympy. sympy also doesn't work well for floats, so you should try to avoid them.

It's quite unclear from the test code what you're trying to do, especially as `PSI` doesn't seem to use `theta` and `phi`. It would be better to leave them out (I left them in the example code to show how functions with more than one parameter would work).

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy import pi, sin, cos, exp, factorial

n = 3
l = 2
m = 2

def sqrt_n(x, n):
    return x ** (1 / n)  # try to avoid floats in sympy as much as possible

def L2(x1, x2, x3):
    # just a dummy function for testing
    return x1 + x2 + x3

def PSI(n, l, m, r, theta, phi):
    a1 = (2 / n) ** 3
    a2 = factorial(n - l - 1)
    a3 = 2 * n * factorial(n + l) ** 3
    a = a1 * a2 / a3
    b = exp(-r / n)
    c = sp.diff(2 * r / n)
    d = L2(2 * l + 1, n - l - 1, 2 * r / n)
    return sp.sqrt(a) * b * c * d

x = sp.Symbol('x')
theta = sp.Symbol('theta')
phi = sp.Symbol('phi')
result = PSI(n, l, m, x, theta, phi)

R = sp.lambdify((x, theta, phi), result, 'numpy')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

count = 20
theta_np = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, count)
phi_np = np.linspace(0, np.pi, count)

THETA, PHI = np.meshgrid(theta_np, phi_np)
x_np = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
XX = R(x_np, THETA, PHI) * np.sin(PHI) * np.cos(THETA)
YY = R(x_np, THETA, PHI) * np.sin(PHI) * np.sin(THETA)
ZZ = R(x_np, THETA, PHI) * np.cos(PHI)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(XX, YY, ZZ)
ax.plot_wireframe(XX, YY, ZZ, color='w', linewidth=0.05)
plt.show()
```

[image: calling matplotlib from sympy functions]

PS: Somewhat related examples:

- [How do I convert sympy expression into a graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59673615/how-do-i-convert-sympy-expression-into-a-graph)
- [Is there a way to put a color bar on a sympy plot3d plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61736951/is-there-a-way-to-put-a-color-bar-on-a-sympy-plot3d-plot)